# Visual Studio 2017, there is no method info's icon

Tags: visual-studio-2017

There is no method info icon. And i got error "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 has stopped working" while im trying to open and close infos. There is no icon, it has bug and it errors.

Can i fix ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Update (8/29): The update with the fix is now available. To update to it, launch the Visual Studio Installer and click the Update button (usually takes a few seconds to appear). You should see an update available to version 15.3.3.

---

Known issue and fix expected to ship in the next update.

Pasting in the workaround [from our Developer Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96914/debuger-icons-missing.html) in the meantime:

> In the meantime, to restore the icons, just open the Autos, Locals,
>   or Watch windows (and re-close if you like). This will need to be done
>   each time Visual Studio is restarted.